# Does Qt/Gtk+ allow programming in two languages at once?

Tags: c++, qt, widget, gtk, language-binding

Widget toolkits like qt/gtk+ have multiple language bindings. Suppose I want to develop an application in c++ but want to use gtk+ C language bindings for my gui. Is it possible to write the source code for the application in one language and use a different language binding for gui? Will the ide interfere too?

Comment: So why not use Qt C++ API.

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of [language bindings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_language_bindings_for_Qt_5) for Qt. Also those blog entries:

http://www.ics.com/blog/using-qt-alternative-programming-languages-part-1

http://www.ics.com/blog/using-qt-alternative-programming-languages-part-2

Also, you could say that Qt is a "two languages" framework at its core, as it has the [QML language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QML) for UI. QML is a declarative language that integrates JavaScript for scripting, it is very easy and fast to develop in.

Qt Creator (the IDE) supports natively C, C++, JavaScript, QML and Python code, maybe even more languages.

As for GTK+, I don't really have any production experience with it, but [it does have different language bindings too](http://www.gtk.org/language-bindings.php).

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to [link your C++ app directly to any C library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12066279/using-c-libraries-for-c-programs), including GTK+. But why do you want to use the GTK+ C API in C++, when [gtkmm](http://www.gtkmm.org/en/) gives you a nice C++ interface to GTK+? You can also [mix C and C++ APIs in gtkmm](https://developer.gnome.org/gtkmm-tutorial/stable/sec-basics-gobj-and-wrap.html.en).

It's also possible to link C++ compiled code to C, as long as it [has the appropriate externs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/199418/using-c-library-in-c-code), but it doesn't seem like QT has C bindings.

Comment: It would be quite backward to use Qt from C... or do application development for that matter. C is too low level.

Comment: Yeah, well, there used to be a QtC, but it's long gone.