# zlib compilation error with VxWorks 6.8

Tags: c++, compilation, zlib, vxworks

I am trying to use gzip compression feature on VxWorks 6.8.

VxWorks development guide help give says,

> You can add the gzip compression feature to your system independently
>   of the Wind River Web Server by adding the zlib library files to your
>   project. To do so, add the files from
>   installDir/components/webcli-4.x/target/src/wrn/wm/common/zlib to your
>   project. Then use the -DWITH_ZLIB compiler flag when you build your
>   system.

I tried it but getting build errors

```
../zlib/zlib_adler32.cpp:21: error: 'z_uLong zlib_z_adler32' redeclared as different kind of symbol

../zlib/zlib.h:822: error: previous declaration of 'z_uLong zlib_z_adler32(z_uLong, const z_Bytef*, z_uInt)'

../zlib/zlib_adler32.cpp:25: error: expected unqualified-id before '{' token 
C:\WindRiver\utilities-1.0\x86-win32\bin\make.exe: *** [.../zlib/zlib_adler32.o] Error 1
```

Note : The files were with .c extension, changed it to .cpp and using C++ compiler. functions are declared with extern "C"

declaration of the function can be [checked here](https://github.com/embedthis/zlib/blob/master/src/zlib.h)

```
ZEXTERN uLong ZEXPORT adler32 OF((uLong adler, const Bytef *buf, uInt len));
```

Any clue?

Comment: *"The files were with .c extension, changed it to .cpp and using C++ compiler"* Hmm that sounds concerning, `zlib` is a `C` library, not a `C++` library. That has important implications regarding linking, name mangling, etc. You should instead compile it as a C library, then link against it, don't try to force it to be a C++ library. [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12066279/using-c-libraries-for-c-programs)

Comment: Thank you. Already using #ifdef __cplusplus extern "C" in code , trying to make C++ lib but if it takes more efforts I would go with C library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with C old style definition not supported by GNU C++

uLong ZEXPORT adler32(adler, buf, len)
    uLong adler;
    const Bytef *buf;
    uInt len;
    {...}

**corrected with**
uLong ZEXPORT adler32(uLong adler, const Bytef * buf, uInt len) {...}

solved my problem.