# g++ undefined reference to libscrypt_scrypt (linker parameterization not the issue?)

Tags: c++, sqlite, undefined-reference

Here's my includes:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstring>
#include <stdio.h> //for snprintf
#include <libscrypt.h>
#include <sqlite3.h>
#include "generator.h" //has no dependencies
```

And here's my g++ 4.2.1 command with compilation errors:

```
# g++ -I/usr/local/include -L /usr/local/lib test.cpp generator.cpp -o test -lscrypt -lsqlite3
/tmp//cctxmw4C.o: In function `insertUser()':
test.cpp:(.text+0x607): undefined reference to `libscrypt_salt_gen(unsigned char*, unsigned long)'
test.cpp:(.text+0x6c3): undefined reference to `libscrypt_scrypt(unsigned char const*, unsigned long, unsigned char const*, unsigned long, unsigned long long, unsigned int, unsigned int, unsigned char*, unsigned long)'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Similar C code compiles fine with GCC. **I do not believe that the order of the parameters is the problem** -- I have tried multiple variations, including moving the -I, -L, and both -l flags. Both scrypt and sqlite3 are C libraries, and sqlite3 throws no errors despite having the header and shared library in -I and -L respectively.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the solution here.

[Using C Libraries for C++ Programs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12066279/using-c-libraries-for-c-programs)

```
    extern "C"{
    void c_function_prototype();
    }
```

or

```
    extern "C" void c_function_prototype();
```

```
If you have it see "The C++ Programming Language (Stoustrup) 4th Edition" p429
```

Comment: Oh wow, I had no clue. Is the preferred way to wrap my #include with extern "C" { ... }, or is there a less messy way?

Comment: Yes. Added to my answer

Comment: Great, thanks for the help and congrats on your (first?) accepted answer!