# Convert C libaries into C++ libs

Tags: c++, c

I started with C recently.
I need to develop a TS3 Plugin, which is controlled over a tcp socket.
I would use a WebSocket.

I've found a bunch of libaries of Websockets but these are only for linux which uses `pThread.h`. And my TS3 Plugin will only run on Windows devices.

It is marked on the [offical TS3 SDK Site](https://www.teamspeak.com/teamspeak3sdk.html) that

> Consisting of the ClientLib and the ServerLib, the TeamSpeak 3 SDK is
>   delivered as shared libraries with a C style coding interface to
>   provide developers direct access to the flexible and feature-rich set
>   of TeamSpeak 3's core functions using simple API calls.
>   With a standard C interface, the TeamSpeak SDK can be easily
>   integrated into high-level programming languages. No matter what
>   technology your application is using, the TeamSpeak SDK will fit in.

So that means that I could easly convert the ts3 api into C++ ?

Comment: Assuming it's well-written C, the C API *is* your C++ API. If you want classes and other stuff, you gotta do that yourself.

Comment: This post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12066279/using-c-libraries-for-c-programs may help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to your question, you don't need to convert the C libraries to C++. Basically, you can link the C library(Linux:*.a/*.so) or (Win:*.dll) and use that function into your corresponding modules.

## Access C Code from Within C++ Source

- In C++ language provides a "linkage specification" with which you declare that a function or object follows the program linkage conventions for a supported language.
- The default linkage for objects and functions is C++. All C++ compilers also support C linkage, for some compatible C compiler.
- When you need to access a function compiled with C linkage (for example, a function compiled by the C compiler, or a function written in assembler), declare the function to have C linkage.

## Declaring Linkage Specifications

Use one of the following notations to declare that an object or function has the linkage of language language_name:

**Example:**

```
extern "C" void howdy(int);
extern "language_name" declaration ;
extern "language_name" { declaration ; declaration ; ... }
```

- The first notation indicates that the declaration (or definition) that immediately follows has the linkage of language_name.
- The second notation indicates that everything between the curly braces has the linkage of language_name, unless declared otherwise. Notice that you do not use a semicolon after the closing curly brace in the second notation.

You can nest linkage specifications, but the braces do not create scopes. Consider the following example:

```
extern "C" {
    void f();              // C linkage
    extern "C++" {
        void g();          // C++ linkage
        extern "C" void h(); // C linkage
        void g2();         // C++ linkage
    }
    extern "C++" void k(); // C++ linkage
    void m();              // C linkage
}
```

All the functions above are in the same global scope, despite the nested linkage specifiers.

## Including C Headers in C++ Code

If you want to use a C library with its own defining header that was intended for C compilers, you can include the header in extern "C" brackets:

```
    extern "C" {
        #include "header.h"
    }
```

**SIDENOTE:** You need to to add this guard in your c header files in order to use that in C++.

```
#ifndef __YOURLIB_H_
#define __YOURLIB_H_

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

int sample_func(int n);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif

#endif
```

[Tutorial to use C lib in C++.](http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/general/13700/)