# Qt link to libparted error

Tags: c++, qt, parted

currently I want to make a Qt application that able to read the HDD partition (maybe in the future able to make patitions on HDD). And I found that libparted can be used for this (my application will be only for Linux).

Already install libparted on machine and here my simple code :

```
#include "parted/device.h"
...
void MainWindow::test() {
    ped_device_probe_all();
}
```

And add this libs to qmake

```
LIBS += -lparted
```

But have error linker :

```
undefined reference to `ped_device_probe_all()'
```

I am not sure whats wrong with my code, is there anyone has the problem, need help please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add `parted.h`:

```
#include <parted/parted.h>
#include <parted/device.h>
... 
void MainWindow::test() {
    ped_device_probe_all();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have encounted this error too. include `parted.h` doesn't help. libparted is C library, so I add `extern "C"` before include device.h, according to [using c libraries for c++ programs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12066279/using-c-libraries-for-c-programs), and it works.

```
extern "C" {
#include "parted/device.h"
}
```