# Compiler version in C++ vs pre-compiled C libraries

Tags: c++, c, linux, gcc, abi

I have a code that uses std=c++20.

I want to use a C library that was build with old gcc version.

Should I recompile the C library using the same compiler ?

If no, how could you judge that the 2 ABIs are compatible?

Comment: Recompiling with the current compiler is a good idea anyway.

Comment: library call standards are same in 90's elf32. call conventions are invented in 80's

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There should be no problem using the library as it is. Don't forget to add `extern "C"` around the function prototypes.

More info: [Using C Libraries for C++ Programs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12066279/using-c-libraries-for-c-programs)

Comment: I hope you mean "function prototypes" and not "header files".